# Layout Problems - Adding Buttons to View Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android Studio and am using a Blank Activity template to try to figure some things out, specifically how to programmatically add Buttons to a view from a List.

I have a List that contains the text for each button as well as some other data that will be used in the click events for them.

First, this is the activity_main.xml layout file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/play_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play Sound"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="48dp" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/menuLayout">

        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the onClick event for the play_sound button I am iterating over the list and then calling this method for each item that needs a button created inside the LinearLayout with id menuLayout:

```
private void createButton(String name){
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText(name);


    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ll.addView(myButton);
}
```

The buttons are created behind the Play Sound button... I have searched through many similar posts on Stack Exchange and tried various things but I have been unable to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: @Boken I approved your edit. In the future, please also remove things like "any help would be appreciated". These things, although polite, are considered noise on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @S.L.Barth sure! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the height of `menuLayout` set to `match_parent`, which in a `RelativeLayout` means it will fill its parent, regardless of other views. If you want it to only display below `play_button`, you should add a `layout_below` parameter, like `android:layout_below="@id/play_button`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried so many different android:layout_XXX options but of course not the one you suggested, which worked great - thanks.